# How to create a dynamic local file path that changes based on the windows user

Tags: windows, windows-10, filepath

I have created a local windows filepath that is dynamic based on the user.

```
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\rest_of_filepath
```

This path works perfectly on my local machine, but when I email it to someone else, they get this error:

```
We can't find 'C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\rest_of_path'. Please make sure you are suing the correct location or web address.
```

How to I get it to work for the others I am sending it to?

Comment: What do you mean by "email it to someone else" and "they get this"? Did you type `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE5\rest_of_path` into an email? When the recipient opened the email, they got an error message? Or did some other steps happen in between?

Comment: Hi Raymond, that is correct. I type the path into an email, I send it to someone else via email and, but then when they click on it they get the error above.

Comment: What happens when you click text in an email message depends on the email program they are using. But it looks like the one they are using doesn't support environment variables. (I wouldn't expect it to. Expanding environment variables is a potential security issue.)

Comment: Regardless, "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\rest_of_filepath" is wrong. It should be "%USERPROFILE%\rest_of_filepath". And even that is probably wrong in general, depending on "rest_of_filepath" because per-user known folders such as "Desktop" and "Documents" can be relocated to another drive or a remote path by policy or user choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `USERPROFILE` is the the correct Environment Variable to use to retrieve the path of the Windows user profile folder. This will work even if the folder is in a "non-default" location. Windows created this Environment Variable for this exact reason. Encasing a word in `%` informs Windows that the word inside the `%` is an Environment Variable. Windows therefore knows to replace the entire '`%USERPROFILE%`' with the path associated to that variable.

In the case of the question the path `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\rest_of_filepath` is used. The `C:\Users\` portion of this path is unnecessary and results in `C:\Users\C:\Users\<userprofilefolder>\rest_of_path` since the Environment Variable will also retrieve that portion of the path.

`%USERPROFILE\rest_of_path` is all that is needed.

Ultimately, even if the HTML interpreter in the email client was able to parse Environment Variables, access to local system files from email is not allowed for security reasons.

Emailing the path and instructing the recipient to copy and paste the the path into the Windows file explorer is the recommended work-around.

src: [Recognized Environment Variables that are recognized only in the user context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables#variables-that-are-recognized-only-in-the-user-context)